# How to avoid the issue "ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980" in ZipFile write() in python 3.10

Tags: python, zip

Recently I encountered the issue `ValueError: ZIP does not support timestamps before 1980` while trying to write a zip file. Searched on google, and most of the solutions tell me to change the file timestamp using "`os.utime()`".
For some other reasons, I find the answer not ideal for me.
Are there any other options to fix the issue or workaround the issue?
Thanks in advance.

ps: Find an answer later, put the answer below, hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a solution later by adding a `strict_timestamps=False` option.
The parameter is passed to class `ZipFile`, then to `ZipInfo.from_file()`:

```
# Inside "from_file()"
if not strict_timestamps and date_time[0] < 1980:
    date_time = (1980, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
elif not strict_timestamps and date_time[0] > 2107:
    date_time = (2107, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59)
```

Original code(which gives the error):

```
import os
import zipfile

file_path = "testFile.log"
timestamp = 0  # Set a custom timestamp (e.g., 0 represents January 1, 1970)

os.utime(file_path, (timestamp, timestamp))
with zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip', 'w') as zipf:
    zipf.write(file_path)
```

Updated code:

```
import os
import zipfile

file_path = "testFile.log"
timestamp = 0  # Set a custom timestamp (e.g., 0 represents January 1, 1970)

os.utime(file_path, (timestamp, timestamp))
with zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip', 'w', strict_timestamps=False) as zipf:
    zipf.write(file_path)
```

Comment: This solution may only be available for newer versions of python, for instance here I am using python 3.10.